# Hide Stylesheet from browsers supporting media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, legacy

I'm trying to create a responsive website. The design has 3 breaks, at 480px, 768px and 1024px. My link-section in the document head looks like this:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 479)" href="320.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width: 480) and (max-device-width: 767)"  href="480.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768) and (max-device-width: 1023)" href="768.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width: 1024)" href="1024.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The problem with this is, that legacy devices that do not understand media queries don't load any of the style sheets.

Is there any way to include a stylesheet that is recognized only by devices that do **not** support media queries, like old Internet Explorers?

I would rather not include this stylesheet for all browsers and then reset or override it.

Thanks,
Jost

Comment: you can detect non supported browsers (IE) and load css dynamically

Comment: What about other browsers than IE? I don't want to use User-Agent detection... (Which would not be needed for IE, but maybe for other browsers)

Comment: Almost all modern browsers do support media queries.